# sizeof packed bitfield returns 4 but I expect 1. How does it come and how I can fix?

Tags: c++

I have a bitfield defined as follows (Where I expect it to be of size: 1):

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
typedef struct
{
    unsigned boolFoo  : 1;
    unsigned pLACEHOLDER : 7;
} KnownBitFlags1_t;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

But after a painfull debugging I finally figgured out that `sizeof(KnownBitFlags1)` returns `4` why?

I also tried:

```
typedef struct
{
    unsigned boolFoo  : 1;
    unsigned pLACEHOLDER : 7;
} __attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) KnownBitFlags1_t;
```

what keeps the sizeof the structure at 4 anyway.

So what can I do to stop padding a array of this structure?

Comment: What is sizeof(unsigned) on your system? I'm guessing it's 2. Also note that any type suffixed with `_t` is reserved by POSIX.

Comment: Why are you not using `unsiged char` since you want one byte?  Also it works here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a60624e32524ffa7

Comment: @Bathsheba: sizeof unsigned is 4 what does that mean for me?

Comment: Your code means "There will be an `unsigned` variable, and within it, 1 bit will mean `boolFoo` and 7 bits will mean `pLACEHOLDER`."  The first phrase in that sentence already suggests that you'll use as much space as a non-bitfield `unsigned` variable.

Comment: btw works [here as well](http://ideone.com/k2gW3D), including array storage.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Is that even allowed?  9.6p1 says that "The bit-ﬁeld attribute is not part of the type of the class member." which suggests that it would be legal to alias a `KnownBitFlags1_t` object by `unsigned&` (on a machine which allows unaligned accesses)... which if the structure is smaller than `unsigned` would lead to all sorts of grief.

Comment: @BenVoigt: it isn't allowed, but thats also not my intention. I don't want to pick up the address of it. I even know ISO/IEC:9899 footnote 106 says: "The unary & (address-of) operator cannot be applied to a bit-field object; thus, there are no pointers to
or arrays of bit-field objects." But don't know what makes you think I want to do that.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm not sure what is in the linked code that would not be considered allowable. The *output* was certainly interesting. Certainly arrays of structures containing bit-fields are allowed, and the last few sentences of the section you cited seem to leave storage and alignment entirely at the whim of the implementation within the structure being stored in the array. (in good company with those pragmas and implementation-supported attributes). If you think I wasn't surprised to see that output, I can assure you I somewhat was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the underlying type. Change `unsigned` to `unsigned char`:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char boolFoo  : 1;
    unsigned char pLACEHOLDER : 7;
} KnownBitFlags1_t;
```

Comment: fixed all my trouble, thanks. Would you mind explaining me why my structure doesn't do what I was expecting?

Comment: When you use `unsigned` then space is reserved for the whole `unsigned int`, i.e. 4 bytes. Regardless of the actually used bits.

Comment: Ah yeah, I found it my self, if you want to improve your answer the quote that supports it is:"`A bit-field is interpreted as a signed or unsigned integer type consisting of the specified
number of bits.`107) If the value 0 or 1 is stored into a nonzero-width bit-field of type
_Bool, the value of the bit-field shall compare equal to the value stored." in document ISO/IEC:9899 TC3 page 102 section 6.7.2.1 point 9. :)